# How to scale imageview and preserve ratio in android?

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-imageview

In my android app, I want to make an imageview and make its height a certain amount. The width needs to be automatically set so that the ratio matches the original image dimension ratio.

This is what I got so far:

```
            ImageView img = new ImageView(context);
            img.setTag(Integer.toString(fish.getId(), 10));
            img.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageviewparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(IMAGESIZE, IMAGESIZE);
            imageviewparams.setMargins(20, 20, 20, 20);
            imageviewparams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
            img.setLayoutParams(imageviewparams);
```

It doesn't not work so well...

Does anyone know how to get it to work?

Thanks.

Comment: can you post an expected image and current result image

Comment: why don't you just calculate the ratio before doing job  and set width's value manually to : newHeight*(preWidth/preHeight)